# Precompute transitive closure of a relation in MiniZinc: Y/N?

Tags: minizinc, transitive-closure

I am trying to solve an exercise in MiniZinc in which a partial ordering relation is given by a 2-D array:

```
enum NODE = { A, B, C, D, E };

int : SOURCE = 1;
int : TARGET = 2;

array[int,1..2] of NODE: edge =
   [| A, B        % edge 1, source & edge 1, target
    | A, E        % edge 2, source & edge 2, target
    | B, C        % edge 3, source & edge 3, target
    | B, D |];    % edge 4, source & edge 4, target
  
set of int: EDGES = index_set_1of2(edge);  

output ["EDGES is \(EDGES)\n"];

predicate ancestor_descendant(NODE: a, NODE: d) =
   exists(edge_num in EDGES)(edge[edge_num,SOURCE]=a /\ edge[edge_num,TARGET]=d)
   \/
   exists(edge_num in EDGES)(
      exists(m in NODE)(
         edge[edge_num,SOURCE]=a 
         /\
         edge[edge_num,TARGET]=m
         /\
         ancestor_descendant(m,d)));
   
constraint assert(fix(ancestor_descendant(A,B)),"Failed a->b");
constraint assert(fix(ancestor_descendant(A,E)),"Failed a->e");
constraint assert(fix(ancestor_descendant(B,C)),"Failed b->c");
constraint assert(fix(ancestor_descendant(B,D)),"Failed b->d");
constraint assert(fix(ancestor_descendant(A,C)),"Failed a->c"); % transitive
constraint assert(fix(ancestor_descendant(A,D)),"Failed a->d"); % transitive
constraint assert(not(fix(ancestor_descendant(E,D))),"Failed a->d"); 
constraint assert(not(fix(ancestor_descendant(A,A))),"Failed a->a");
```

The above just implements the following tree and a predicate that asks whether node
`a` is ancestor of node `d`.

[image: Tree]

However, I feel answering the predicate `ancestor_descendant/2` can become expensive for large `edge` arrays, which might be a hindrance if the predicate is called a lot during optimization.

Should I expect MiniZinc to memoize/cache the (immutable) predicate results by itself? Should I do so myself? Although I don't see how to avoid setting up an (card(NODE)^2)*2 sized array of `true` and `false` (unlike in Prolog where I would just keep the positive answers of the predicate in the database).

Comment: Did you make the graphic by yourself? What is the license, can I use it?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse Sorry for the late reply, I haven't been to SO in some time. Done with yed. Sure thing, grab it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiniZinc does indeed implement memoization for any decision variable expression in the model, as a form of [Common Sub-expression Elimintation (CSE)](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/flattening.html#defining-subexpressions). This should make sure that the result of the calls and the results of the exists for any two nodes will only exists once.

In general, it has been found that CSE through memoization is not worth it for parameter expressions, since it is costly in memory and parameter expressions are generally quick in MiniZinc. So if you are running into problems during the flattening stage, then I would suggest computing the descendants explicitly beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

A tree topology is a typical example where you do not necessarely need caching.

Its rather that a good program transformation does the job, respectively a theorem from
transitive closures, that left and right transitive closures are the same.

I am using `edge/2` and `edge2/2` so that the testing also works
for a Prolog system that has only first argument indexing:

```
setup :- between(1,1024,N), M is N//2, assertz(edge(M,N)), fail.
setup :- edge(M,N), assertz(edge2(N,M)), fail.
setup.

anc(X,Y) :- edge(X, Y).
anc(X,Y) :- edge(X, Z), anc(Z, Y).

anc2(X,Y) :- edge2(Y, X).
anc2(X,Y) :- edge2(Y, Z), anc2(X, Z).
```

You can run `setup` once. Later you get quite dramatic results:

```
?- time((between(1,1000,_), anc(0,1024), fail; true)).
% 3,076,001 inferences, 0.178 CPU in 0.181 seconds (98% CPU, 17298884 Lips)
true.

?- time((between(1,1000,_), anc2(0,1024), fail; true)).
% 37,001 inferences, 0.003 CPU in 0.003 seconds (99% CPU, 14659667 Lips)
true.
```

So repeatedly calling freshly `anc2/2` should be fine. For a balanced binary tree with n nodes it only needs O(log(n)) time, not like `anc/2` which needs O(n) time.